# Problemas no getDownloadUrl firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-storage

Olá, estou com uma dificuldade no **getDownloadUrl** do firebase.

Após a ultima atualização do firebase storage meu app parou de funcionar.

Está apresentando erro na **Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();**

```
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                Map newImage = new HashMap();
                newImage.put("profileImageUrl", downloadUrl.toString());
                mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(newImage);

                finish();
                return;
            }
        });
```

**Apresenta o erro**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual erro está sendo apresentado?

Comment: Acabei de adicionar uma foto com o erro que estou passando

Comment: Consegue com `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrlAsync()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse método foi removido à favor do [`StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getDownloadUrl()). Esse método retorna um `Task<Uri>`. Então você tem de adicionar um listener ao `Task` para obter a downloadUrl:

```
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUrl) {

                        Map newImage = new HashMap();
                        newImage.put("profileImageUrl", downloadUrl.toString());
                        mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(newImage);

                        finish();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```